# Is it possible to show CiviMails within our Drupal CMS system?

Tags: drupal, civimail

When CiviMail gives a permanent link to a public mailing it simply creates a raw html page for the email. Eg, on a link like this: civicrm/mailing/view?id=1528, we see the mailing exactly as it was sent out, and the html code of this page is exactly what was sent out in the mailing.

Thus the public view of the email is outside of our CMS, and doesn't benefit from our website's navigation menus, branding or any of the features our CMS provides.

We're using Civi 5.13 and Drupal 7.68... and it would be great if it were possible to put the public view of the mailings inside of Drupal's page construction, rather than outside it.

I can see how this would be possible using Views... but is there a more obvious way that I'm somehow missing?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say in the question, you can build a View based on the CiviCRM Mailings tables so eg Body - HTML etc.

Alternatively you could build your mailing body in Drupal, then use a View based on that to drop a 'views token' in to your mailing.

Comment: Thanks Pete, that gives good clarity. (And in case anyone is wondering what a 'views token' means, It's possible to add a View to a Civimail. very cool.)